# Video & Audio Kit on a Budget

Tags: video, camera

My group has a budget of ~£1000 to spend on high quality recording equipment so I need to do a little background research before I go off and advise them about what to buy.

The aim is to be able to record high quality video with good sound. Often is the case that the sound lets the videos down. So I'm assuming that we'll need a separate sound kit.

Therefore, I am in the market for:

- A video camera which records at least HD quality video and manual zoom (as well as automatic) - ~£600
- A sound recording kit which either attaches to the camera, or is totally separate in which case the sound will be synced later on. - ~£200
- Perhaps some lighting so help with indoor scenes - ~£200

What kinds of products do you recommend I look into? I'm relatively new to professional quality video recording so any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there a specific format you need to record onto; or are you open to opinions?

Answer (score 3):

On the audio side, I've been extremely happy with my [Sony M10](http://pro.sony.com/bbsc/ssr/cat-audio/resource.latest.bbsccms-assets-cat-audio-solutions-pcmm10.shtml). It takes two batteries and MicroSDHC cards. With a pair of fully-charged eneloops, it can fill up a 16GB card and the 4GB internal memory at 24/44.1 and still have some power left. Audio quality is good, but the close-set omnis don't give you a lot of stereo separation. You will also need to manually sync your audio with your camera.

Given your budget, does it make more sense to rent gear than purchase?

Comment: +1 for rent. £1000 is going to get you reasonably good amateur equipment. You aren't getting anywhere near professional quality with this much cash.

Answer (score 0):

https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/8442/its-2013-is-hacked-gh1-still-the-best-cheap-cinematic-video-camera

This camera body can be had for £200-400. Use a "micro four thirds adapter" to attach any high-end used lens you can get your hands on. Beware, however, if you use such an adapter, zoom and focus motors do not work. Or instead you can use a real micro four thirds lens if you need focus and zoom motor.